# changing date entry formats in r

Tags: r, date, format

I have an issue with my date format with entries having two formats `(d/m/y and d.m.y)`. I have been trying to change the `d.m.y` format `to d/m/y` but to no avail.

sample data:

```
anim <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
tdate <- c("2/12/2013","3/12/2013","4/12/2013","11.01.2014","12.01.2013","13.01.2013")
zap <- data.frame(anim,tdate)
zap
  anim      tdate
1    a  2/12/2013
2    b  3/12/2013
3    c  4/12/2013
4    d 11.01.2014
5    e 12.01.2013
6    f 13.01.2013
```

EDIT:

I also have a date format with `15.12.13 (d.m.y)`. I got`0013-12-13` when using `as.Date(zap$tdate,format="%d/%m/%Y")`.

```
anim <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
tdate <- c("2/12/2013","3/12/2013","4/12/2013","11.01.2014","12.01.13","13.01.13")
zap <- data.frame(anim,tdate)
zap
  anim      tdate
1    a  2/12/2013
2    b  3/12/2013
3    c  4/12/2013
4    d 11/01/2014
5    e   12/01/13
6    f   13/01/13
> zap$tdate <- as.Date(zap$tdate,format="%d/%m/%Y")
> zap
  anim      tdate
1    a 2013-12-02
2    b 2013-12-03
3    c 2013-12-04
4    d 2014-01-11
5    e 0013-01-12
6    f 0013-01-13
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Seems like a simple text replacement - `gsub(".","/",zap$tdate,fixed=TRUE)` or `chartr(".","/",zap$tdate)`

Comment: @thelaemail, many thanks! that was a great help.

Comment: @thelatemail, i have edited my question. i also have a date format slightly different (12.01.13) then the two (2/12/2013; 11.01.2014) that i gave.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, convert it to a character, then set the first two digits to 20.

```
zap$tdate<-as.character(zap$tdate)
substr(zap$tdate,1,2)="20"

zap$tdate
[1] "2013-12-02" "2013-12-03" "2013-12-04" "2014-01-11" "2013-01-12" "2013-01-13"
```

Then you can set it back to a date class if you'd like.

```
zap$tdate<-as.Date(zap$tdate)
```